# Error Code:1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1452

Im trying to add in this data. However, It's not allowing me. How do I add the grades in that is also linked to the student?

The error code that is appear is "

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`university`.`grade_report`, CONSTRAINT `grade_report_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Student_number`) REFERENCES `STUDENT` (`Student_number`))

Possible Solution?

```
Create database UNIVERSITY;

USE UNIVERSITY;


CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
Name VARCHAR(150),
Student_number INT,
Class INT,
Major VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (Student_number)
);

CREATE TABLE UNIT (
Unit_name VARCHAR(120),
Unit_number VARCHAR(20),
Credit INT,
School VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (Unit_number)
);

CREATE TABLE SECTION (
Section_id INT,
Unit_number VARCHAR(20),
Semester INT,
Year INT,
Lecturer VARCHAR(150),
PRIMARY KEY (Section_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Unit_number) REFERENCES UNIT(Unit_number)
);

CREATE TABLE GRADE_REPORT (
Student_number INT,
Section_id INT,
Grade INT,
FOREIGN KEY (Student_number) REFERENCES STUDENT(Student_number),
FOREIGN KEY (Section_id) REFERENCES SECTION (Section_id)
);


INSERT INTO STUDENT
VALUES 
('Smith', 17, 1, 'CS'),
('Brown', 8, 2, 'CS’);

INSERT INTO UNIT
VALUES
(‘Intro to CS’, ‘IN101’, 8, ‘CS’),
(‘Data Structures’, ‘CS302’, 8, ‘CS’),
(‘Database’, ‘IAB130’, 8, ‘IS’),
(‘Discrete Maths’, ‘MATH120’, 10, ‘MATH’);

INSERT INTO SECTION
VALUES
(85, ‘IN101’, 1, 2012, ‘Smith’),
(102, ‘CS302’, 1, 2012, ‘King’),
(103, ‘IN101’, 2, 2013, ‘Baily’),
(96, ‘MATH120’, 1, 2012, ‘Jones’);
```

Problem is here:

```
INSERT INTO GRADE_REPORT
VALUES
(17, 85, 7),
(8, 103, 5),
(8, 102, 6),
(8, 85, 6),
(9, 85, 5),
(17, 96, 4);
```

Comment: The problem is that you are assigning 3 values to GRADE_REPORT table, but there are 4 columns in there. In this case you must define the column names, just as @user3349436 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

U must defined the field for each data destination like this

```
INSERT INTO GRADE_REPORT (`Student_number`,`Section_id`,`Grade`) VALUES (17, 85, 7), (8, 103, 5), (8, 102, 6), (8, 85, 6), (9, 85, 5), (17, 96, 4);
```

Comment: I've added you code into SQL, however it's returning "Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`university`.`grade_report`, CONSTRAINT `grade_report_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Student_number`) REFERENCES `STUDENT` (`Student_number`))"